# problemas al actualizar manjaro xfce

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

Buenas estaba actualizando manjaro xfce y la lapto se apago a media actualizacion, y cuando intente prenderla daba un problema con el grub, esto ya lo resolvi pero hay algunas app que no se inician ejemplo telegram y ahora al instalar algo nuevo siempre me muestra este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. Esta pregunta podría ser formulada en [su].

Comment: Sería mucho mejor si publicas el texto y no una imagen de esos mensajes. Por otro lado, intenta `sudo pacman -Syyu --overwrite usr/lib/*` Esto debiera sobreeescribir esos archivos en lugar de mostrar como error que están vacíos.

Comment: Al ejecutar el comando sudo pacman -Syyu --overwrite usr/lib/* , me arroja un error ara todos los paquetes que están ahi: error: no se ha encontrado el paquete: /usr/lib/zsh
advertencia: «/usr/lib/zsh» es un archivo, ¿quiso decir -U/--upgrade en lugar de -S/--sync?